# PHP - Is there a better way to search a large string than with multiple IFs

Tags: php, string, variables, if-statement, search

I have a variable called `$data` that is storing a large amount of data.  I know that data will contain ONE of these words… `cheese`, `crackers`, or `fruit`.  Or, it could possibly contain none of those words.   Right now, I do this….

```
if (strpos($data,"cheese")!==false) $food="cheese";
else if (strpos($data,"crackers")!==false) $food="crackers";
else if (strpos($data,"fruit")!==false) $food="fruit";
else $food=”none”;
```

So,  if cheese is found, the data is only being searched once. If cheese isn’t found, the data is being searched again, because it first looked for cheese, didn't find it, then had to search again to look for crackers.  See the problem?  So, if no food is found, the data ends up being searched 3 times before the food variable is finally set (am I right, is that how it works?).

I’m wondering if there’s a more efficient way to search.  I thought of a possible way, but I don’t know how to do it…
What if I searched for all three foods at once like this…

```
if (strpos($data,"cheese")!==false or
strpos($data,"crackers")!==false or
strpos($data,"fruit")!==false)
$food=THE WORD THAT WAS FOUND GOES HERE
```

I want to be able to set the food variable to what was found.  If this is possible, Am I correct in thinking this would be much faster because you’re searching the data only once?  Or is PHP still searching 3 times to look for each item?    And is it even possible to set the food variable to what was found?

Comment: Does `$data` only contain the word, or does it contain other words too?

Comment: Your second way is really the same as the first insofar as it still calls `strpos()` three times. Have you determined that doing it three times is actually a problem? Is it noticeably slow? If not, micro-optimisations are rarely worth the bother.

Comment: You could try using `preg_match()` and a match such as `(cheese|crackers|fruit)`, then checking what actually got matched; but I'm not convinced it's going to be faster.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you not using an array for that? It would be easier

```
$words = ["cheese","crackers","fruit"];
$food = null;
foreach ($words as $value){
    if (!$food && strpos($data, $value))
        $food = $value;
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, though this probably isn't really any faster, just more dynamic. Micro-optimizations are rarely worth doing but I think your answer is a better solution than OPs

Comment: That might be what I'm looking for.  Does that reduce the amount of times the data is searched?

Comment: In the current way its written this won't reduce the amount of times the data is searched, I made an answer which is very similar but involves a break, so as soon as the search string is found the data variable is no longer checked

Answer (score 2):

The best way would probably be to use an array:

```
$data = "cheese platter";
$toCheck = [
    "fruit",
    "crackers",
    "cheese"
];
$food = false;
foreach ($toCheck as $item){
    if (strpos($data, $item) !== false) {
        $food = $value;
        break;
    }
}`
```

Comment: upvote for the break to make it possibly slightly quicker

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler. Not necessarily faster.

```
$food = 'none';
if (preg_match('#(cheese|crackers|fruit)#', $data, $match)) {
    $food = $match[1];
}
```

Comment: I've seen some good answers here, this might be the best.  My concern was that if my data variable is very large, I don't want to have to search it over and over to find words.  I would think that would be slow.  If your method looks for all the words in one search of the data, I would think it would have to be faster.   The array examples I've seen here with the for-each loops would still be searching multiple times.   I might run some tests...    Thanks

Comment: I would say make some huge test files with random words in. Then put your special words within them and benchmark. Unless you're scanning really really huge strings, you might find it's not anywhere near as slow as you're expecting.

Comment: @CheeseFlavored How do you define "very large"? because you are very likely worrying about a time difference that is not going to matter to the user

Comment: If the data variable is being sent over HTTP, the time taken to transfer it is likely to dwarf the time taken to scan it a few times anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, and you're right, it may not matter in my case, but there's another factor to consider also... In my example, I searched for only 3 words.  What if I had to search for hundreds of possible words.  Then the data might need to be searched 100's of times before it finds one.  I would think a slow down would occur at some point based on the size of data and number of times searched.

Comment: _Are_ you going to have to search for 100s of words? If not, don't worry about it. If so, I'd say the basic approach is wrong and you need to think of something else.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an interesting experiment.  I ran some timing tests on my original method with the IF statements, then with the array method posted by Jammy and Jason, then with the preg_match method posted by Daren.  I was quite surprised. PHP is SUPER FAST no matter what method you use.  I created a variable called $data that was 1meg long and seached for any of 10 words.  when no words were found I got this for average time...

```
If_method = 0.01 seconds
Array_Method = 0.006 seconds
Preg_match = 0.1 seconds
```

So, even after looping through all that data 10 times, the IFs and array loops were at least 10 times faster than preg match, but Pregmatch is still going to finish before you can blink.

Comment: Something to bear in mind, with a preg match you will have to add items to the list every time you want to change it, with an array you can pull it from elsewhere without having to worry about changing your logic :)

Answer (score -1):

This will give you all the positions of the words

```
$data = explode(' ', $data); 
$words= array('cheese', 'fruit', 'crackers');
var_dump(array_intersect($data, $words));
```

Then you can affect food based on the result.

Comment: How do you know words are seperates by a space?

Comment: He's data is a string and i did a separator ' ' here he can choose whatever separator he have.

Comment: I see what you are getting at but with the information given it can't be proven the format, but say for example the list has "grapefruit" in it then that won't be a fruit which can be an issue, or if the format was something like "Apple-fruit" it wouldn't work